# Updating an multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to update an value in an multi dimensional array which was not working can any one tell me what is the issue in the below code.

```
<?php
$array_m= array();
array_push($array_m,array('md5'=>'a','count'=>1));
array_push($array_m,array('md5'=>'b','count'=>1));

foreach ($array_m as $key=>$val) 
{

    if($val['md5']=='a') {
    $val['count'] =5;
    break;
    }
}
print_r($array_m);
```

Comment: Try by reference `$key=>&$val`

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($array_m as $key=>$val)
```

This just loops through the values, you can't update them.  You need to use a reference, so you can update the array.

```
foreach ($array_m as $key=>&$val)
```

Note the `&`, that will make it a reference.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `$key` so you can reference the array using that:

```
if($val['md5']=='a') {
    $array_m[$key]['count'] = 5;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Chnage your Code like following,

```
<?php
$array_m= array();
$array_m[] = array('md5'=>'a','count'=>1);
$array_m[] = array('md5'=>'b','count'=>1);

 foreach ($array_m as $key=>$val) 
 {

     if($val['md5']=='a') {
     $val['count'] =5;
    break;
    }
}
print_r($array_m);
```

Comment: I think you forgot to change something :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of 5 like this:

`$array_m[$key]['count'] = 5;`